# How to create an ephemeral request model for the Django admin panel

Tags: redis

I have a request model for ChatGPT. I need to make it ephemeral so that it does not require migrations and it is not stored in the postgresql database, but only in redis, using get - set queries to work with it. In the Django admin panel there should be a field for quickly editing a request, but without the ability to add these requests. In theory it sounds clear, but in practice there are problems

So far everyone looks like this

```
models.py:

from django.db import models

class Prompt(BaseFakeModel):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Автор блога')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Должность автора')
    audience_age = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Возраст аудитории')
    audience_positions = models.JSONField(verbose_name='Топ 10 Должностей аудитории')
    audience_gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Пол аудитории')
    popular_topics = models.TextField(verbose_name='Популярные темы в текущем месяце')
    suggested_topics = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Предложенные темы')
    request_text = None  # Добавляем поле request_text в код, но оно не будет сохранено в базе данных

    @property
    def request_text(self):
        return "Текст запроса"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Промт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Промты'
        app_label = 'recommender'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} - {self.position}'

admin.py:
from .forms import PromptForm
from .models import GPTProcessingRequest,Prompt
from apps.admin import ADMIN_SITE
from .redis_client import save_request
from apps.admin.base import ExtendedModelAdmin
class PromptAdmin(ExtendedModelAdmin):
    form = PromptForm
    # Определение полей, отображаемых в интерфейсе администратора
    list_display = ('id','get_request_text')

    def get_request_text(self, obj):
        # Здесь можно реализовать логику для получения текста запроса, например, из других полей модели
        return "Текст запроса"

    get_request_text.short_description = 'Текст запроса'
    get_request_text.admin_order_field = 'request_text'

    # Отключение возможности добавления новых объектов
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        save_request(obj.request_text)



# Регистрация моделей в административной панели
ADMIN_SITE.register(GPTProcessingRequest)
ADMIN_SITE.register(Prompt,PromptAdmin)
```

With all this code, on the change page prompt. There is nothing, I expect to see a field for editing the request and a save button. Which works through the set method for the redis database

The full technical specification sounds something like this: Prompt contains a prompt template for preparing recommendations. This is an ephemeral model without migrations and data storage in a relational database. The model is needed in order to quickly create an interface for editing industrial items in the administrative panel using Django.